# Editable $Method$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$); in Structural Search template of Android Studio is not returning ::: public Editable getText()

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

[I am trying to find this method in Search Structurally option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bcqv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the class containing the method you are trying to find does not have sources. If you attach sources, Structural Search should be able to find it.

Comment: I am using All as Places option.

Comment: And you are right. when i manually go down to that method i get JetBrains decompiler usage warning with download sources option. Is there any other way without downloading sources to achieve what i want? Because downloading sources might make the project size huge, right?

Comment: Sources are usually not very large, because you can just keep them compressed in a zip or jar. IntelliJ IDEA can still access them from there and there's no need to modify them. Additionally sources will also make debugging very much easier. So I recommend just attaching sources.